# Remove first line of XML file using PERL only IF contains "XYZ"

Tags: xml, perl

I am downloading an XML file using wget, but sometime the file has text in the first line that I need to get rid off.

It currently has "131" on the first line and "0" on the last line.

I need a way of removing these lines if it contains this information. I can't do a perl find and replace, in-case it is not there but the proper first line contains "131".

Does this make sense?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Example, sometimes it is this:

```
131
<element>
<example>content</example>
<example>content</example>
<example>content</example>
<example>content</example>
</element>
0
```

It is sometimes like this (correct)

```
<element>
<example>content</example>
<example>content</example>
<example>content</example>
<example>content</example>
</element>
```

Comment: The second file is not XML either, there needs to be one root element

Comment: Hi, this was just a quick example, rather than writing lots of code.

Comment: Are you dealing with files or HTTP responses? That's a "chunked" HTTP response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**That's a job for `sed`!** You would'nt find quicker or simplier:

If you're sure of the two values, you could simply:

```
sed -e  '1{/^131$/d};${/^0$/d}' -i mybrokenfile
```

But whith the following command, `sed` while **remove** any first and/or last line containing only a number:

```
sed -e '1{/^[0-9]\+$/d};${/^[0-9]\+$/d}'
```

This could by run with files as param and backup files auto-generation:

```
sed -e '1{/^[0-9]\+$/d};${/^[0-9]\+$/d}' -i.bak files*
```

Explained:

- there is two parts, `1` and `$` are *address*: `1` for first line and `$` for last line.
- Following block present another form of address-by-condition: `/^[0-9]\+$/` mean *lines that begin with one or more characters between `0` and `9` and ending immediately after.
- At this matching lines (on first or last line), the command to execute is `d` for *delete line*.

This could be written:

```
sed -e '1{
            /^[0-9]\+$/d
        }
        ${
            /^[0-9]\+$/d
        }' -i.bak files*
```

as well.

**Edit**:

As I hate to write more than one time... approx anything;

There is a way to do some tricky thing, but only on 1st and last line.

First, the same sample could by written:

```
sed -e '1ba;$ba;bb;:a;/^[0-9]\+$/d;:b;' -i.bak files*
```

So this is **1** byte shorter! But especially the *operation* is written only once:

Explained:

- `:a` and `:b` are labels where to branch (jump) to
- `ba` and `bb` are branch instruvtion respectively to `:a` and `:b`.
- `1` and `$` are address as previously described
- `/.../d` is previously described too, mean *delete lines matching regex*

And could by written:

```
sed -e '
    1ba;
    $ba;
    bb;
   :a;
    /^[0-9]\+$/d;
   :b;
  ' -i.bak files*
```

Sample of application, using `s/../../` instead of only `d`:
Modify version info only if present at 1st or last line:

```
 sed -e '1ba;$ba;bb;:a;s/\(Id: .*,v\).*\(Exp\)/\1'"$(
             date +" $VER %F %T $USER ")"'\2/;b;' -i files*
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this may get you where you want to be.

Supposing you just did a wget for sample.xml then:

```
perl -pi -e '$/ = undef; s{(?: \A [^<]* | [^>]* \z )}{}xmsg;' sample.xml
```

That strips anything non < from the beginning of the file and anything not > from the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a comment, you want to use `wget --save-headers` and use a proper HTTP Response parser. That's actually quite simple:

```
use HTTP::Response qw( );
my $response = HTTP::Response->parse($raw_response);
my $body = $response->decoded_content( charset => 'none' );
```

Given the response including headers via `$raw_response`, the above code will return the transmitted XML (or whatever) document in `$body`.

---

Original response:

That's an HTTP chunked response.

```
if ($file =~ /^[0-9]+\r?\n/) {
   my $chunked = substr($file, 0, length($file), '');
   for (;;) {
      $chunked =~ s/^([0-9]+)\r?\n//
         or die;

      my $chunk_len = $1
         or last;

      length($file) >= $chunk_len
         or die;

      $file .= substr($chunked, 0, $chunk_len, '');
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi ikegami, thanks for the reply. Yes, I am grabbing the feed from HTTP using wget. Is there any way I can use your code with a cronjob? Can I use your code in one line and run it via cron?

Comment: Why is wget retuning the raw response instead of the response body?

Comment: It'll be a very long line, but yes, there's nothing special that will prevent it from running as a one-liner or from `cron`.

Comment: Hi @ikegami, thanks again. Please forgive my lack of knowledge. I currently have `wget -O /home/account1/public_html/getxmls/example.xml 'http://api.example.com/1.0/content?token=SNGIGS54QMZTUGT3QMSTQ4LQGTLUI3GTMQSLG';` running in a `cron`, how can I include your code within this? thanks

Comment: You need to add `--save-headers`, for starters. But why not just use LWP?

Comment: @ikegami for ascii chunked HTTP1/1 files: `perl -e 'while (! /^0\r?$/) { $_=<>;s/\r//; my $l=hex;my $c=0; ($_=<>) && ($c+=length) && print  while $c<$l;};'` This won't eat buffer 8k buffer and work well (Nota `/\n/` is useless if you dont touch `$/` ;-)